# Blender 2.8 Multiple object follow path animation

Tags: animation, modifiers

Hello i tried to make an animation where a multiple object array with equal spacing offset completing a loop.

Something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlzcxUanU3o but in blender 2.8

most tutorial i found were kinda old and didn't help anymore

or is there a any add-on can be used for this kind of animation